# ReactJS: Updating array inside object state doesn't trigger re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a react hooks function that has a state object `apiDATA`. In this state I store an object of structure:

```
{
name : "MainData", description: "MainData description", id: 6, items: [
{key: "key-1", name : "Frontend-Test", description: "Only used for front end testing", values: ["awd","asd","xad","asdf", "awdr"]},
{key: "key-2", name : "name-2", description: "qleqle", values: ["bbb","aaa","sss","ccc"]},
...
]
}
```

My front end displays the main data form the object as the headers and then I map each item in `items`. For each of these items I need to display the `values`and make them editable. I attached a picture below.

[image]

Now as you can see I have a plus button that I use to add new `values`. I'm using a modal for that and when I call the function to update state it does it fine and re-renders properly. Now for each of the words in the `values`I have that chip with the delete button on their side. And the delete function for that button is as follows:

```
const deleteItemFromConfig = (word, item) => {
    const index = apiDATA.items.findIndex((x) => x.key === item.key);

    let newValues = item.value.filter((keyWord) => keyWord !== word);

    item.value = [...newValues];

    api.updateConfig(item).then((res) => {
      if (res.result.status === 200) {
        let apiDataItems = [...apiDATA.items];
        apiDataItems.splice(index, 1);
        apiDataItems.splice(index, 0, item);
        apiDATA.items = [...apiDataItems];
        setApiDATA(apiDATA);
      }
    });
  };
```

Unfortunately this function does not re-render when I update state. And it only re-renders when I update some other state. I know the code is a bit crappy but I tried a few things to make it re-render and I can't get around it. I know it has something to do with React not seeing this as a proper update so it doesn't re-render but I have no idea why.

Comment: FWIW, you only need a single `.splice` call: `apiDataItems.splice(index, 1, item);`

Comment: Yes I had that before but I just broke it down hoping it will do something :)). Thank you for the observation anyways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not updating because you are changing the array `items` inside `apiDATA`, and React only re-render if the pointer to `apiDATA` changes. React does not compare all items inside the `apiDATA`.

You have to create a new `apiDATA` to make React updates.

Try this:

```
      if (res.result.status === 200) {
        let apiDataItems = [...apiDATA.items];
        apiDataItems.splice(index, 1);
        apiDataItems.splice(index, 0, item);
        setApiDATA(prevState => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                items: apiDataItems
            }
       });
      }
```

Comment: Your answer will be more useful if you explain what changed and why you changed it (i.e. why does it solve the problem).

Comment: *" but the pointer to the array is the same"* No, the array is different (`let apiDataItems = [...apiDATA.items];` creates a new array). The problem is that `apiDATA` refers to the original value (and that's what you changed).

Comment: @FelixKling ahh yeah you are right, my mistake. I will correct the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `splice` isn't a good idea, since it mutates the arrays in place and even if you create a copy via `let apiDataItems = [...apiDATA.items];`, it's still a shallow copy that has original reference to the nested values.

One of the options is to update your data with `map`:

```
const deleteItemFromConfig = (word, item) => {
  api.updateConfig(item).then((res) => {
    if (res.result.status === 200) {
      const items = apiDATA.items.map(it => {
        if (it.key === item.key) {
          return {
            ...item,
            values: item.value.filter((keyWord) => keyWord !== word)
          }
        }
        return item;
      })

      setApiDATA(apiData => ({...apiData, items});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You are not addressing the actual problem: Updating `apiData` itself (`setApiDATA(data);` is wrong).