# react setState() not triggering re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have component which receives data from other file and setting into state:

```
const [sortedPlans, setSortedPlans] = useState(
    data.Plans.sort((a, b) => b.IndustryGrade - a.IndustryGrade)
  );//data is from external file
```

After setting the state, sorting the data and rendering the initial screen, I have function that sorts the sortedPlans whenever it is called:

```
const sort = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    const newArr = sortedPlans.sort((a, b) => {
      return b[event] - a[event];
    });
    console.log(newArr);
    return setSortedPlans(newArr);
  };
```

The problem is that this is never triggering a re-render of the component. I want when I set the new state to be able to see it inside the jsx. Why when I console.log(newArr) the results are correctly sorted but this setting of the state not triggering re-render? Here is the sandbox:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-shape-r9ps3p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: React will only re-render if you set a new value. `sortedPlans.sort` sorts the array in-place however and returns the same array.

Comment: This is a similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478050/reactjs-updating-array-inside-object-state-doesnt-trigger-re-render

Comment: @FelixKling So basically I am setting the same thing as React assumes that this is the same array

Comment: It *is* the same array: `var arr = [3,2,1]; console.log(arr === arr.sort());`. React will only re-render if necessary, i.e. if values change. React doesn't know that you mutated this array. That's why in React you usually create copies of mutable values before you mutate them.

Comment: This is about object's reference. Take a look at this issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19181

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here you go: [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-almeida-xtm3le?file=/src/App.js).

You should first make a shallow copy of the array you want to modify. Then set that array as the new state. Then it re-renders the component and you are able to filter like you want.

```
  const sort = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    //shallow copying the state. 
    const newArr = [...sortedPlans];

    //modifying the copy
    newArr.sort((a, b) => {
      return b[event] - a[event];
    });
    console.log(newArr); //results here are correctly sorted as per event
    
    //setting the state to the copy triggers the re-render.
    return setSortedPlans(newArr);
  };
```

Comment: You are right. I will accept the answer but can we explain why this is needed

Comment: React components automatically re-render whenever there is a change in their state or props. In your example, `sortedPlans.sort` is sorting the array in place and returning that very same array, and thus you never actually update the state. The easiest way is to just copy the state, modify the copy, then setting the state equal to the copy and then the state gets updated and the component re-renders.

Comment: React would compare with the previous state using strict comparison `===` to decide whether to kick rerender. `===` would return true for the same object (or array which is an object too technically). After mutation, the object (or an array) stays technically the same, although mutated (i.e. a field is changed) or sorted in your case. Indeed, `arr = []; arr.sort(); arr === arr`